# Where can I download JNLP 1.2?

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, jnlp

JNLP-bin-1.2 is needed when installing NetBeans on Gentoo (Linux), and for license problems, I have to download it manually. Then I tried to visit the page http://java.sun.com/products/javawebstart/download-jnlp.html, which is provided by Gentoo documentation, but I just cannot download it, for downloading has closed by Oracle. So how can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/archive-download-142935.html)  Java Web Start 1.2 is shipped as part of the Java 2 Platform, Standard Edition 1.4.1 (J2SE 1.4.1). You may need to download the entire JRE.